# Swift : football-data API doesn't work

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I'm trying to use football-data.org api. I wrote some code same with before I did sample. But this api is using token and I didn't figured out how to add and do that.

I did these code and nothing happens :

```
func getData(){
    let url = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/424/fixtures"))
    url.addValue("my token is here", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    url.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(url) { (data, response, error) in
        self.setLabels(data!)
    }

    task.resume()
}

func setLabels(MatchData: NSData){
    //var jsonError: NSError?

    do{
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(MatchData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

        if let sys = json["soccerseason"] as? NSDictionary{
            if (sys["href"] as? String) != nil{
                let seasonsUrl = sys["href"] as! String

                print(seasonsUrl)
            }


        }
    }
    catch{
        //error

    }
}
```

I'm not getting value or something. I'm new with json. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You're ignoring the error in the catch. Don't do this, always handle the error (print the message, at least).

Comment: I'm reading the json queries now. maybe I implement wrong way. But interesting to nothin happens when I compiled the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"soccerseason"` is in `"_links"`, like this:

```
if let links = json["_links"] as? [String:AnyObject],
    sys = links["soccerseason"] as? [String:String],
    seasonsUrl = sys["href"] {
        print(seasonsUrl)
}
```

This is for the main one.

I've also noticed there's one (the same one, actually) in each dictionary in the main array:

```
if let fixtures = json["fixtures"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for fixture in fixtures {
        if let links = fixture["_links"] as? [String:AnyObject],
            sys = links["soccerseason"] as? [String:String],
            seasonsUrl = sys["href"] {
            print(seasonsUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

The URLs are in the `_links` part in each dictionary in the `fixtures` array:

```
if let fixtures = json["fixtures"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for fixture in fixtures {
        if let links = fixture["_links"] as? [String:[String:String]],
            season = links["soccerseason"],
            seasonsUrl = season["href"],
            awayTeam = links["awayTeam"],
            awayTeamUrl = awayTeam["href"] {

                print(seasonsUrl)
                print(awayTeamUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

And `awayTeamName` and `homeTeamName` are at the same level than `_links` inside the array of dictionaries:

```
if let fixtures = json["fixtures"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for fixture in fixtures {
        if let awayTeamName = fixture["awayTeamName"] as? String,
            homeTeamName = fixture["homeTeamName"] as? String {

            print(awayTeamName)
            print(homeTeamName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much. I understood this first step. But I want to get home and away teams. Are these objects under the fixtures? If you explain how can I read this json data as well, I'll really apperciate that :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. There's everything you need now. The rest of the JSON follows the same logic.

Comment: Oh I'm really thankful for that.  I'll keep going to rest of the json with your samples. You are the best! Thanks again!

Comment: hey @Eric ! I have an issue for this json : [link](http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/424/leagueTable) I tried `[[String:AnyObject]]` for A, but doesn't work. Could you help me please?

Comment: It should work. Maybe you forgot a step somewhere? Have a look: https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwe_cNsFSNG0bmQfMiWG9JLEdpo-J18Rg8

Comment: Oh thanks! I have forgotten the standings data on the top. I tried first with A and get the team name. So how can I get each every name? valueForKey doesn't work for that unfortunately :) Sorry for more questions, but I am learnig get json by myslef :( I am trying to figured out that thing.

Comment: oh okay I found it. a[1]["team"] is the way I can get the team name. Cool!